# Application of the result set's fetch size kills the program

Tags: java, oracle, resultset, ojdbc

This is a very interesting question for me, and I hope that you will help me solve it. I am making a query to select all rows from an Oracle DB table. There is used the oracle jdbc driver. To avoid connection timeout, queries are performed using rownum in increments of 100 rows. Everything would be fine, but the program freezes on row 91 of the result set trying to do resultSet.next(). Wherein there are no any exceptions. I tried to looking for the reason of this behavior and realized that the matter is in the fetch size of the result set. The default value of fetch size is 10. This behavior looks like these 10 rows are pulled out from the result set and program is freezed when we get into the freed space. Then we set fetch size 0, all works perfect. Is this the expected behavior? And if so, why? In the example below, this problem is bypassed by exiting the loop by row number.

```
private static volatile int bottomRow = -99;
private static volatile int topRow = 0;
private static final String SQL = "SELECT * from (select m.*, rownum r from keyspace.table m) where r >= ? and r < ?";

public static void select(Connection connection) {
    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement(SQL)){
        while (true) {
            incrementCounters();
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, bottomRow);
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, topRow);
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
          // rs.getFetchSize(); -> default value is 10
            if (rs.next()) {
                do {
                    rs.getString("id");
                    rs.getString("customer_name");
                    /* some logic */
                    if (rs.getRow() == 90) {
                            break;
                    }
                 } while (rs.next());
            } else break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } 
}

private synchronized static void incrementCounters() {
    Thread.sleep(700);
    if (topRow != 0) {
        bottomRow += 90;
        topRow = bottomRow + 100;
    } else {
        bottomRow += 100;
        topRow += 100;
    }
}
```

jdbc driver version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Configurations of pool properties

```
private static DataSource ds=null;
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
    if (ds==null){
        synchronized (Source.class.getName()) {
            if (ds==null)
                try {
                    DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(1);
                    String driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
                    PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
                    p.setUrl(url);
                    p.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
                    p.setUsername(username);
                    p.setPassword(password);
                    p.setJmxEnabled(false);
                    p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
                    p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
                    p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1 from dual");
                    p.setTestOnReturn(false);
                    p.setTestOnConnect(false);
                    p.setValidationInterval(5*1000);
                    p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(120000);
                    p.setMaxActive(500);
                    p.setInitialSize(0);
                    p.setMinIdle(30);
                    p.setMaxIdle(100);
                    p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
                    p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(120000);
                    p.setLogAbandoned(false);
                    p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
                    p.setJdbcInterceptors("org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState; org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer; org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementCache");
                    ds = new DataSource();
                    ds.setPoolProperties(p);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("error {}",e.getMessage());
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
        }
    }
    return ds.getConnection();
}
```

Comment: Is there anything unusual about the rows?  For example, are the rows returning large CLOBs that might cause memory problems?

Comment: Jon, yes. There are two CLOBs, but each has a size of about 300 bytes. 
Also a row contains three fields (strings) of no more than 50 bytes each.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really answer your question, as there're a lot of details missing, but the one thing I have to point out here is that the code seems needlessly way over the top, and that's probably the reason for it's seemingly faulty behavior.

If you're selecting all rows (or running a select with conditions for that matter) I suggest you use a simple `select * from [table]` and leave the rest out.

What you have to understand is that the JDBC driver handles way more than just query compilation and data transfer, and overcomplicating queries prevents it from optimizing whatever you're doing.

In addition, keep in mind that running multiple selects with boundries creates a ton of overhead, which on Oracle specifically, even with good indexing, doesn't always fly.

For example, running a query to fetch 1000 records creates a resultset, opens a stream and find the records, filter them, sort them, transfers records in whatever batch sizes the JDBC driver thinks makes most sense. (on db side there's only one pointer moving from 1st to last)

running the same thing but 10 time with hardcoded 100 record sizes creates overhead where 10 resultsets need to be created, the db server needs to find the records 10 times, filter them 10 times, sort them 10 times and skip the appropriate amount to get to the batch you're requesting, which means 0, then 100, then 200... (on the db side every batch has to create a new pointer and then move it to the appropriate position before transfer can start)

Now, for 1000 records it shouldn't really matter, but it's good practice to always write elastic code, but if you have to do that on a table with let's say 20 million records (which I have done, and that's how I learned) the job goes from (in my case) minutes to weeks.

As for timeouts, they're a non-issue unless it takes too long to process data you already transported, but if that's the case I wouldn't look to query optimization, but rather how data processing is handled once it's already in (maybe have some form of parallelims introduced to have more work at the same time done).

If, for your specific case, you could provide more details like what's stored in the table, how many records there are and so on, I'll be glad to update my answer.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ivan, thanks for the answer. A table (in my case this is a view) contains five columns. There are two CLOBs, but each has a size of about 300 bytes. There are also three Strings of no more than 50 bytes each. The view doesn’t contain many rows. It is around 200 000 rows. 
Unfortunately, this query "select * from [table]" does not work. On the DB side, there is a time limit on a query. In my case, the connection is broken on a row of something around 20 000.

Comment: "running the same thing but 10 time with hardcoded 100 record sizes creates overhead..." yes. it is true. thanks for the comment. but, unfortunately, refactoring in this direction will not give answer to my question. you can set fetch size 0, and go in increments of 1000 rows. everything will work perfectly. but the question is on the other side. i see a very strange behavior for me and do not understand it. and hope to find explanation of my case. why application of the result set's fetch size does kill the program?

Comment: Ivan, i have a feeling that the issue is in the auto commit. i'll check this suspicion the other day.

Answer (score 0):

"To avoid connection timeout, queries are performed using rownum in increments of 100 rows"

You can check on why the connection timeout occurs in the first place. Eg: do you get a timeout when you try to run the query in sqldeveloper or toad.

The query "SELECT * from (select m.*, rownum r from keyspace.table m) where r >= ? and r < ?" looks like you wish to implement pagination equivalent. I suggest if you are interested in getting batches of data for display on the UI you would want to order by the inner query to a deterministic record set.

Eg: It should be SELECT * from (select m.*, rownum r from keyspace.table m ORDER BY ) where r >= ? and r < ?.

And if you are in 12c and above check out the option of row limiting clause
https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1

Comment: George, thank you for your answer. for safety reasons (db side is a high load data) there is a time limit on a query. time limit is deliberately setted. is it good to use OFFSET and LIMIT for limiting clause? rownum has better perfomance, because OFFSET and LIMIT recalculates row positions for each query. you could run your application using OFFSET and LIMIT and see how the speed of execution change from query to query. each query will be slower and slower moving forward in a data array.

Comment: @BobJarvis I meant ORDER BY <primary key/deterministic column orders>

Comment: @AlexanderSuvorov. I suspect the OFFSET and LIMIT would be better optimized than using ROWNUM with DIY form of pagination(reason its a built in keyword as against a rownum structure which is being used in current query). In the current query you use there  could be overlaps of data(Eg: pages with toprow 1 to 10 might contains records which are present in 11-20

Comment: In this link the value of rnk=20 is that of [11,C] which is the 11th position according to the way in which data is loaded.https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=802cee63acd8f8ae5f61cd9d07a56bf8

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph, it is very interesting that data could be overlaps. thank you fo this remark. what about the execution of various SQL commands, my opinion is based on the behavior that i saw. i can’t say that you are wrong. i admit i do not know which version of Oracle DB is used in my project. probably the optimization of OFFSET and LIMIT you are talking about in our version is not yet implemented